# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite

When I want to add data to sqlite this error pops up. Previously in SQLite there was already one data. Can you help provide a solution to my problem?
[android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAQE1.png)

```
public long insertMovie(MovieFav movieFavorite) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId());
        args.put(TITLE, movieFavorite.getTitle());
        args.put(OVERVIEW, movieFavorite.getOverview());
        args.put(RELEASE_DATE, movieFavorite.getRelease_date());
        args.put(VOTE_AVERAGE, movieFavorite.getVote_average());
        args.put(POSTER_PATH, movieFavorite.getPoster_path());
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    }


public class DbHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "movielist";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_FAV = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s"
            + " (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL)",

            TABLE_MOVIE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_ID,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_PHOTO,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE
    );




    DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_FAV);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIE);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to have this line :-

```
args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId());
```

in the **insertMovie** method.

Without the line, the **id** will be automatically generated (1 then 2 then 3 (likely)).

If you do include the above line then an attempt will be made to insert **BUT** if the value is already used in that column, in other rows, then you will get the UNIQUE constraint conflict. That is, primary keys have to be UNIQUE and thus even without coding UNIQUE they are as if UNIQUE was coded (i.e the UNIQUE constraint is implied).

*Note; you very likely do not need **AUTOINCREMENT**, `+ " (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +` will still auto-generate the **id**, but will be more efficient. As per :-*

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

As per the comment :-

> If the args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId()); is not added then the data will be duplicated

here's an example :-

### DbHelper.java

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "movielist";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = DbContract.TABLE_MOVIE;
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_FAV = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s"
            + " (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
            " %s TEXT NOT NULL)",
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_ID,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_PHOTO,
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE
    );

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    public DbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long insertMovie(MovieFav movieFavorite) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE, movieFavorite.getTitle());
        //<<<<<<<<<< ID REMOVED >>>>>>>>>>
        args.put(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW, movieFavorite.getOverview());
        args.put(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE, movieFavorite.getRelease_date());
        args.put(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE, movieFavorite.getVote_average());
        args.put(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_PHOTO, movieFavorite.getPoster_path());
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR THE DEMO TO LIST MOVIES WITH THE ID >>>>>>>>>>
    public void logAllMovies() {
        Cursor csr = sqLiteDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("MOVIELIST",
                    "Title is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE)) +
                    "\n\tID is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_ID)) +
                    "\n\tOverview is \n\t\t" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW))
                    /* and so on */
            );
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_FAV);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to complete (may be different) >>>>>>>>>>
    private class DbContract {

        private static final String TABLE_MOVIE = "movie";

        private class  MovieListFavorite {
            private static final String MOVIE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
            private static final String MOVIE_TITLE = "title";
            private static final String MOVIE_OVERVIEW = "overview";
            private static final String MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
            private static final String MOVIE_PHOTO = "photo";
            private static final String MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
        }
    }
}
```

### MovieFav.java

```
public class MovieFav {

    private long id;
    private String Title;
    private String Overview;
    private String Release_date;
    private String Vote_average;
    private String Poster_path;

    public MovieFav() {
    }

    public MovieFav(String title, String overview, String release_date, String vote_average, String poster_path) {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Overview = overview;
        this.Release_date = release_date;
        this.Vote_average = vote_average;
        this.Poster_path = poster_path;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return Overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        Overview = overview;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return Release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
        Release_date = release_date;
    }

    public String getVote_average() {
        return Vote_average;
    }

    public void setVote_average(String vote_average) {
        Vote_average = vote_average;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return Poster_path;
    }

    public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
        Poster_path = poster_path;
    }
}
```

### Code in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DbHelper mMyDBHlpr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMyDBHlpr = new DbHelper(this); //Instantiate Database Helper

        // Add some Movies WITHOUT specifying ID
        mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("Gone with the wind","It blows","2019-01-01","medium","//posters/movies/gwtw"));
        mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("The Magnificent Seven","Magnificent","2019-10-01","medium","//posters/movies/tms"));
        mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("The Lord of the Rings","I'll ring you about this one","2015-12-01","great","//posters/movies/lotrp1"));
        mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("War of the Worlds","Alien to me","2010-01-01","ok","//posters/movies/wotw"));
        // Output Movies information to the log INCLUDING ID
        mMyDBHlpr.logAllMovies();

    }
```

## Result in Log :-

```
2019-09-28 19:51:52.242 7088-7088/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is Gone with the wind
        ID is 1
        Overview is 
            It blows
2019-09-28 19:51:52.243 7088-7088/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Magnificent Seven
        ID is 2
        Overview is 
            Magnificent
2019-09-28 19:51:52.243 7088-7088/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Lord of the Rings
        ID is 3
        Overview is 
            I'll ring you about this one
2019-09-28 19:51:52.243 7088-7088/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is War of the Worlds
        ID is 4
        Overview is 
            Alien to me
```

As the above always attempts to add 4 rows, if run a second time then :-

```
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is Gone with the wind
        ID is 1
        Overview is 
            It blows
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Magnificent Seven
        ID is 2
        Overview is 
            Magnificent
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Lord of the Rings
        ID is 3
        Overview is 
            I'll ring you about this one
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is War of the Worlds
        ID is 4
        Overview is 
            Alien to me
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is Gone with the wind
        ID is 5
        Overview is 
            It blows
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Magnificent Seven
        ID is 6
        Overview is 
            Magnificent
2019-09-28 20:00:52.454 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Lord of the Rings
        ID is 7
        Overview is 
            I'll ring you about this one
2019-09-28 20:00:52.455 7188-7188/aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb D/MOVIELIST: Title is War of the Worlds
        ID is 8
        Overview is 
            Alien to me
```

i.e. the same rows have been added BUT with other id's (5-8 this time)

## No Duplicate Movies

If what you want is to not duplicate data, like the entire movie so that 5-8 will not be added then you can create a UNIQUE constraint appropriate to the data that you don't want to be duplicated. The **id** will never be duplicated it cannot be and isn't useful as far as the data is concerned, from the aspect of Movie information (the id is very useful from a database point of view).

Assuming that you never want a Movie to be added if there is already a Movie with the same Title and the same Release date then you could make the combination of Movie's Title and Movie's Release date UNIQUE.

e.g. for the above then your code for the creation of the table could be (see comments) :-

```
private static  final String DATABASE_NAME = "movielist";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = DbContract.TABLE_MOVIE;
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_FAV = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s"
        + " (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
        " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
        " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
        " %s TEXT NOT NULL," +
        " %s TEXT NOT NULL" + //<<<<<<<<<< REMOVED CLOSING PARENTHESIS
        /* ADDED the UNQIUE CONSTRAINT ON THE Title and release date */
                ", UNIQUE ("
                + DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE +
                "," + DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE
                + ")" + // END Of THE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT
                ")", //<<<<<<<<<< END OF CHANGES FOR ADDING UNIQUE constraint
        /**
         * NOTE AS THE SCHEMA HAS CHANGED THE DATABASE NEEDS TO BE DELETED (altering is possible but harder)
         * THEREFORE TO INTRODUCE CHANGES >>>>>>>>>>UNINSTALL THE APP AND THEN RERUN<<<<<<<<<<.
         */
        DATABASE_TABLE,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_ID,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_PHOTO,
        DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE
);
```

## The Error (isn't as such)

Regarding the message, it is a trapped exception, it doesn't result in a failure and the reported row(s) are not added.

If you wanted to bypasses the reporting in the log then you would have to use an alternative method that entails generating the insert SQL that uses `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO the_table (a_comma_separated_list_of_the_columns_for_which_data_is_supplied) VALUES(a_comma_separated_list_of_values)` (the values that make up a sentence describes the values as a whole, it is not a special value that would be used).

In short the insert method could be :-

```
public long insertMovieAlternative(MovieFav movieFavorite) {
    String insertSQL = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE +
            "(" +
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_TITLE + "," +
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_OVERVIEW + "," +
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE + "," +
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE + "," +
            DbContract.MovieListFavorite.MOVIE_PHOTO +
            ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    SQLiteStatement sqlstmnt = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(insertSQL);
    sqlstmnt.bindAllArgsAsStrings(new String[]{
            movieFavorite.getTitle(),
            movieFavorite.getOverview(),
            movieFavorite.getRelease_date(),
            movieFavorite.getVote_average(),
            movieFavorite.getPoster_path()
    });
    Log.d("ALTINSERTSQL",sqlstmnt.toString());
    return sqlstmnt.executeInsert();
}
```

- NOTE the line `Log.d("ALTINSERTSQL",sqlstmnt.toString());` isn't needed, it was added to show what the SQL generated, as is passed to SQLite e.g.
- `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO movie(title,overview,release_date,vote_average,photo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`
- The ?'s are bound by the SQLite API (in a similar what to using String.format) and hence the use of the **bindAllArgsAsStrings** to allow SQlite to replace each ? with the appropriate value. This prevents SQLInjection.

Consider the above and using :-

```
    mMyDBHlpr = new DbHelper(this); //Instantiate Database Helper

    // Add some Movies WITHOUT specifying ID
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("Gone with the wind","It blows","2019-01-01","medium","//posters/movies/gwtw"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("The Magnificent Seven","Magnificent","2019-10-01","medium","//posters/movies/tms"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("The Lord of the Rings","I'll ring you about this one","2015-12-01","great","//posters/movies/lotrp1"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovie(new MovieFav("War of the Worlds","Alien to me","2010-01-01","ok","//posters/movies/wotw"));

    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovieAlternative(new MovieFav("Gone with the wind","It blows","2019-01-01","medium","//posters/movies/gwtw"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovieAlternative(new MovieFav("The Magnificent Seven","Magnificent","2019-10-01","medium","//posters/movies/tms"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovieAlternative(new MovieFav("The Lord of the Rings","I'll ring you about this one","2015-12-01","great","//posters/movies/lotrp1"));
    mMyDBHlpr.insertMovieAlternative(new MovieFav("War of the Worlds","Alien to me","2010-01-01","ok","//posters/movies/wotw"));

    // Output Movies information to the log INCLUDING ID
    mMyDBHlpr.logAllMovies();
```

This tries to add the same set of movies BUT the second lot won;t because of the UNIQUE constrain added for the Movie Title Moview Release date combination BUT the log doesn't include the exception messages (there are no exceptions because INSERT OR IGNORE acts as a noop (do nothing) if the conflict occurs).

The log instead will be :-

```
2019-09-28 20:52:06.304 D/ALTINSERTSQL: SQLiteProgram: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO movie(title,overview,release_date,vote_average,photo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
2019-09-28 20:52:06.305 I/chatty: uid=10419(aso.asoinmemorysbtofiledb) identical 2 lines
2019-09-28 20:52:06.306 D/ALTINSERTSQL: SQLiteProgram: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO movie(title,overview,release_date,vote_average,photo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
2019-09-28 20:52:06.307 D/MOVIELIST: Title is Gone with the wind
        ID is 1
        Overview is 
            It blows
2019-09-28 20:52:06.307 D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Magnificent Seven
        ID is 2
        Overview is 
            Magnificent
2019-09-28 20:52:06.307 D/MOVIELIST: Title is The Lord of the Rings
        ID is 3
        Overview is 
            I'll ring you about this one
2019-09-28 20:52:06.307 D/MOVIELIST: Title is War of the Worlds
        ID is 4
        Overview is 
            Alien to me
```

Comment: If the args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId()); is not added then the data will be duplicated.

Comment: @SatyaRac if you don't supply the value i.e. no `args.put`, then the underlying SQL will not supply a value and as the column is an alias of the rowid column then the value will be auto-generated and be unique. As per *On an INSERT, if the **ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** column is not explicitly given a value, **then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer**, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.*

Comment: @SatyaRac, I believe that I now understand and hopefully the additional sections to the answer will address the issues (in short there wasn't really an issue, the messages were only information that the duplicates were not added and came about because the exception has trapped and handled and reported on).

Answer (score 1):

why you are insertion id while you set id auto increment
remove  `args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId());` from insertiong query like below

```
public long insertMovie(MovieFav movieFavorite) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(TITLE, movieFavorite.getTitle());
        args.put(OVERVIEW, movieFavorite.getOverview());
        args.put(RELEASE_DATE, movieFavorite.getRelease_date());
        args.put(VOTE_AVERAGE, movieFavorite.getVote_average());
        args.put(POSTER_PATH, movieFavorite.getPoster_path());
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
    }
```

Comment: If the args.put(ID_MOVIE, movieFavorite.getId()); is not added then the data will be duplicated.